# Travelling salesman problem: on-paper algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

Are there any fast algorithms for solving the TSP on paper (without computer) given the matrix with weights of all edges. The matrix is non-symmetrical, meaning the road from $a$ to $b$ doesn't have the same weight as $b$ to $a$.

Comment: Fast *algorithms* to *solve* the problem? Definitely not. You should instead focus on approximation algorithms and heuristics. See here for example: http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:358638/fulltext01.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) is easy to do without a computer.

Of course it is an approximation algorithm.